# docker build can not access host network

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to build a docker image by Dockerfile, the docker version is 1.12.6.

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-1.12.6-71.git3e8e77d.el7.centos.1.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.8.3
 Git commit:      3e8e77d/1.12.6
 Built:           Tue Jan 30 09:17:00 2018
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-1.12.6-71.git3e8e77d.el7.centos.1.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.8.3
 Git commit:      3e8e77d/1.12.6
 Built:           Tue Jan 30 09:17:00 2018
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
```

the dockerfile failed at `yum makecache`

```
ADD CentOS-Base.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN yum clean all
RUN yum makecache
```

The host server is in innet network, it install packages from the inner yum repo.
I run build dockerfile on host server, when install packages in container, the network is unreachable for the inner yum repo, how to let the docker can access the host server's network env?  like `docker run --network=host`?
I try to use `docker build --network=host` but it not working

In the dockerfile can't access all IPs which the host can access.

Comment: which docker version are you using? the build command has the network option since 1.13.0 https://github.com/moby/moby/releases/tag/v1.13.0-rc4

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke 1.12.6 `docker build -h` show `--network string          Connect a container to a network (default "default")`

Comment: Even with the help showing the option, I would first try to update docker. Your version is quite old.